# Print in landscape and portrait in same document

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

My customer want to print letters in landscape orientation e.g

> ABCDE

and print another letters in the same page but in a portrait orientation from top to down e.g :

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

by using the printing control in windows forms in c#. So how can i do this ?? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u tried something?

Comment: refer this for landscape http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.landscape(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i tried to print the page twice; once for landscape ;second for portrait with use of thread.sleep(30000) while the customer set the paper into printer ; but this solution didn't like my customer.

Comment: @sedalnas: That aspect is totally not contained in your question. Could you please change your text (and possibly the title, as well) to express what you are actually looking for and what you have tried so far? (P.S.: Please remove the part "in c#" from your question title. That information is best conveyed by the respective tag.)

Comment: first export to pdf, then printing from the pdf viewer

Comment: i can tell u code in which acc to user choice landscape or portrit u can print.

Comment: i think the idea of exporting to pdf is great but how can i do it ?

Comment: u can also print multiple pages on one sheet use that that is the awesome solun in one page u can take landscape in another portarit i can give u that code.

Comment: @Arjun Chaudhary: i'm waiting for code

Answer (score 0):

1. u can do it in many language just follow every step on this site and
   u can do this.
   http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Print+Multiple+Pages+on+One+Sheet
   it will also help for your orientation selection also
2. for setting orientation use this code

> ```
>  protected override void OnPrintPage(System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
>     {
>         // Run base code
>         base.OnPrintPage(e);
> ```

```
        //Declare local variables needed

        int printHeight;
        int printWidth;
        int leftMargin;
        int rightMargin;
        Int32 lines;
        Int32 chars;

        //Set print area size and margins
        {
            printHeight = base.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom;
            printWidth = base.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left - base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right;
            leftMargin = base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left;  //X
            rightMargin = base.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top;  //Y
        }

        //Check if the user selected to print in Landscape mode
        //if they did then we need to swap height/width parameters
        if (base.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape)
        {
            int tmp;
            tmp = printHeight;
            printHeight = printWidth;
            printWidth = tmp;
        }

        //Now we need to determine the total number of lines
        //we're going to be printing
        Int32 numLines = (int)printHeight / PrinterFont.Height;

        //Create a rectangle printing are for our document
        RectangleF printArea = new RectangleF(leftMargin, rightMargin, printWidth, printHeight);

        //Use the StringFormat class for the text layout of our document
        StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit);

        //Fit as many characters as we can into the print area      

        e.Graphics.MeasureString(_text.Substring(RemoveZeros(curChar)), PrinterFont, new SizeF(printWidth, printHeight), format, out chars, out lines);

        //Print the page
        e.Graphics.DrawString(_text.Substring(RemoveZeros(curChar)), PrinterFont, Brushes.Black, printArea, format);

        //Increase current char count
        curChar += chars;

        //Detemine if there is more text to print, if
        //there is the tell the printer there is more coming
        if (curChar < _text.Length)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
            curChar = 0;
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: have u got the answer.